# HP Envy TS 15 Ubuntu compatibilty?

Tags: system-installation, laptop

I m planning to partition my current laptop **HP Envy TS 15** to install Ubuntu.

Is Ubuntu going to run on this machine?

Comment: You can test this by making a Live CD/USB.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Saiarcot895, 
best way to know if your PC is compatible with Ubuntu : **it is to test Ubuntu on your PC**, directly yourself with a **Live Disk** OR a **Live USB**:

- see *How to burn a DVD on Ubuntu* [from Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) or [from Mac](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx) or [from Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu)
- see *How to create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu* [from Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) or [from Mac](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) or [from Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

Then follow [these instructions for installing Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) (you will get the choice to Install or Test)

[image]